# How to remove gap between UIPickerView Components of different background colors

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am using different background colors for each component of a UIPickerView. There is a white gap between each compnent. I want to remove that.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
```

does not seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set pickerView background color as clear color and add n numbers of views of equal width behind the picker view where n is number of component.[image: UIPickerView with different background color component]